# How to respect network use settings in Android

Tags: android

My app performs some backgound data collection and I'm adding support for the user network preferences, such as performing background updates and data roaming.  I have the following checks already:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(cm.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
...
NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
```

with the required entries in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

This all appears to be working fine, but I was wondering if I should be checking anything else?  I was worried about checking for data roaming but the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isAvailable%28%29) state that `networkInfo.isAvailable()` checks this for me.  So are there any other checks I need to implement for network settings?  Anything else in this area I should be aware of?

Comment: Good question. Does network info also not have a isRoaming method. (And are you developing app to only North America area, if not this could be a problem, since the network protocol could be different).

Comment: Yes, there is an `isRoaming()` method.  I've not used it so far as `networkInfo.isAvailable()` appears to return `false` if the network is roaming and the user has disabled Data Roaming.  The app will be UK-only - I don't **think** this has an effect on the code I have so far, but if I were to implement some of the checks in the answers I would have to check a different NETWORK_TYPE.

Comment: I was curious. I browsed thro  the source code and documentation. isNetworkAvilable is reliable as any, since it checks if you are in home network or not. ( after all if it fails, your application is not the only one in trouble ;))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user may change the settings while your background app is running.  The API recommends that you listen to the broadcast message:

```
ConnectivityManager.ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED
```

Perhaps you are checking cm.getBackgroundDataSetting() prior to sending data, and I suspect this would be sufficient.  However, listening to the broadcast message will let you resume sending background data when the settings are changed.

I believe that either listening to the broadcast message or checking the settings before sending data will suffice.  [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED) recommends the former.

Comment: I have a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` to perform the downloads.  I then set an alarm using the `AlarmManager` to trigger a background download.  Each time the receiver is triggered it performs the checks in my post.  I suppose I could also listen to the broadcast message you suggest so that if background updates have been off and have just been turned back on I can trigger an immediate download.  Or I could just wait for the next scheduled download to occur.  I guess I have to make a design decision... thanks for the post.

Answer (score 6):

Additionally to your checks I also do check for roaming state for 3g network:

```
NetworkInfo info = m_connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
int netType = info.getType();
int netSubtype = info.getSubtype();

if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX)  
{
   //no restrictions, do some networking
}
else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE && 
     netSubtype == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS)
{
   //3G connection
   if(!m_telephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming())
   {
      //do some networking
   }      
}
```

My application uses a lot of data, so I do not allow data downloading on non-3g mobile networks.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks for the post.  Wouldn't `!m_telephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()` prevent a download even if the user has ticked the box to allow Data Roaming?

Comment: If you haven't ticked 'Data roaming' in settings, no one will be able to use mobile networks while in roaming. But in my case I needed to prevent heavy network usage even if roaming is enabled ( for 'light' requests I didn't do this roaming check ). So, yes, this will disable application's network activity even if device-wise roaming is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Like @inazaruk, I a also trying to prevent (for the user possibly expensive) network transfers when roaming or downloading images while on GPRS only. Therefore in [Zwitscher](http://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/) I've implemented a NetworkHelper that checks against users preferences on romaing and minimal network state; https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/helper/NetworkHelper.java
The matching preferences are here: https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/res/xml/preferences.xml#L30