# Android - Downloading data from the internet >> catch connection errors

Tags: android

In my app i connect to a server, which responds with an xml. I parse it with the SAX Parser, and get the data.

The question is:

**What is the best way to handle connection issues?**

(At this moment if there is no internet connection available the app simply continues showing the `ProgressDialog` i implemented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as following the suggestion of Heiko Rupp, you can also check for the availability of a network connection prior to performing your download.  See [my post on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634633/how-to-respect-network-use-settings-in-android).

Comment: no, this doesn't work very well. Because checking the connection before downloading doesn't assure you that the connection won't be lost during the downloading process..

Comment: @junmats you should use both approaches at the same time.  That is, check that a connection is available before you start, then catch and deal with errors as they occur during the download process.  For example, queuing and resuming the download when a connection become available again.

Comment: yes, that was what I would like to suggest to him.. I just commented on his prior comment that your code works very well, but in fact, joining yours code and Heiko's code is way much better. But then, I just realized that you have also suggested it..:-) Sorry...m\/

Answer (score 4):

So you basically do (Pseudo code)

```
ProgessDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this).show();
Sax.parseStuff();
pd.dismiss();
```

In this case, wrap the parsing stuff and cancel the dialog on Exception

```
ProgessDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this).show();
try {
   Sax.parseStuff();
}
finally {
   pd.dismiss();   // or cancel
}
```

You can also do a `try { .. } catch (XYZException e ; pd.cancel(); throw e)` if you want to process the Exception in a different layer of your app.

Comment: I tried your method, but if i deactivate the internet connection, the app still get stuck showing the ProgressDialog...

Comment: @Abramodj If you check for the availability of a network connection before you pop-up the dialog and attempt to connect to the remote server, then you can avoid this issue.  See the link in my post.