# Upload data when Wi-Fi is connected?

Tags: android

I'm making an app that is essentially a web form. I fill it out and send it to a website to be processed. But I only want it to send the data when connected to wifi.

I was thinking of putting the data into a tinyDB then running a check for wifi immediately. If connected it would submit the form and delete the db entry. I'd probably also run a check when the app is loaded and closed. It's important that I don't lose the data.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the form is small, you may not even need a db, you could just use SharedPreferences
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref , unless you have multiple rows of the user answering again and again then this might not be the best solution

here's some network check code if you need it

```
ConnectivityManager manager =(ConnectivityManager)activityOrContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if(info==null || !info.isConnected()){          
     return false;// network not active
}
```

not sure if you need this, you may already know how to do this or have it figured out

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my question [How to respect network use settings in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634633/how-to-respect-network-use-settings-in-android).  Some of the answers demonstrate how to check the network type.

Answer (score 1):

You can prompt the user to ask him if he wants to enable Wifi, and then you can enable it from code. Take a look at [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class.